# Having an issue with MapPageRoute in Vb.Net Global.asax

Tags: vb.net, routes, expression

I am having an issue where the I am trying to use some Regular Expression in a constraint.  The issue is it is evaluating the Regex as a string, and throwing an error.  "Cannot convert String '\d+' to long"

Here is the code
                `.MapPageRoute("Parts",
                            "{PartName}/{Part}/",
                            "~/Inventory/Default.aspx",
                            Nothing,
                            New RouteValueDictionary(New With
                            {.Part = "\d+"}))`

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much the exact code and it works fine for me.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("CMS", "{folderID}/{pageTitle}", "~/index.aspx", False, Nothing, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.folderID = "\d+"}))
```

I'm using .net 4.0 - perhaps you have 3.5 sp1?